# Spring Data JPA - java.sql.Timestamp is getting null for rest of the list or set of entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Consider that i have a entity.

```
Class Employee {
@Id 
private integer id; 
private String name; 
private Timestamp effectiveFrom;
}
```

and i have a list of value to it..

```
List<Employee> Employees = new ArrayList<>();

[1,"Employee1", "2019-10-10 00:00:00.000"]
[1,"Employee2", null]
[1,"Employee3", "2019-10-10 00:00:00.000"]
[1,"Employee4", "2019-10-10 00:00:00.000"]
```

When i do - repository.saveAll(Employees);

The first and second employee are saved correctly from third employee on wards the effectiveFrom column (Timestamp) - is getting null..

Is it expected behavior by Spring Data JPA ?

Comment: How did you map the string to a java.sql.Timestamp?

Comment: Timestamp.ValueOf(StringValue)

Answer (score 1):

First you should not use the same id for any object. I would suggest to add the `@GeneratedValue` annotation for the primary key. I have create the entity with [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) like that:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp effectiveFrom;

    public Employee(String name, String effectiveFrom) {
        this.name = name;
        this.effectiveFrom = effectiveFrom == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(effectiveFrom);
    }
}
```

At the end I create a simple jpa repository and save all entities:

```java
@Bean
CommandLineRunner run(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
    return args -> {
        List<Employee> employees = List.of(new Employee("Employee1", "2019-10-10 00:00:00.000"),
                new Employee("Employee2", null), new Employee("Employee3", "2019-10-10 00:00:00.000"),
                new Employee("Employee4", "2019-10-10 00:00:00.000"));

        employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
        employeeRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    };
}
```

The console output looks like that:

```
Employee(id=1, name=Employee1, effectiveFrom=2019-10-10 00:00:00.0)
Employee(id=2, name=Employee2, effectiveFrom=null)
Employee(id=3, name=Employee3, effectiveFrom=2019-10-10 00:00:00.0)
Employee(id=4, name=Employee4, effectiveFrom=2019-10-10 00:00:00.0)
```

Please have a look at this short example. If you cannot find the error in your code, please post your code so I can have a look.